# error when compiling c++ code with g++

Tags: c++, stl, linker, g++

i get error of this type: 
"in function ... multiple definition of ..." 
"... first defined here" 
"warning: size of symbol ... changed from  to  in "

*the code is compiled with the flags: -ansi -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror 
*STL is used

is there any explanation for that?

thank you in advance

Comment: Post your code please.  Also when you edit your question to add it in make sure you format it as code so it shows up properly.

Comment: If you want help with code that won't compile, post the code that won't compile. If you're worried about secrecy, just change the variable names and strip it down to the bare components causing the problem.

Comment: "warning: size of symbol ... changed from to in " - that is error from linker saying that a global symbol is defined more than once and the definitions are different (have different size).

Comment: To avoid the error, only define the symbol once. (And to enable us to help you more specifically, post the code that is causing the error.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explanation? The error message you quoted is already an explanation as exhaustive as it can ever get. Something (a variable) is defined more than once in the same scope. The compiler gave you the name of the offending variable. The compiler reported the error at the second definition and supplied an additional message that points out the first definition. That's everything you need to know to find the problem and then some. What more to explain here?